# LSTM: How to effectively comprehend and use return_sequences=False?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm performing a multivariate time series analysis. I intend on running this network many, many times with different batch sizes and hyperparameters. Therefore I have been keeping things general so far and assuming

```
B := Number of batches

T := Number of timesteps per batch

N := Number of features per timestep
```

My end goal is to call model.predict on one batch (that hasn't been used to train, of course). Thus it will look like this

```
prediction = model.predict(unknown)
unknown.shape = (T, N)
prediction.shape = (N,)
```

I've been trying out loads of networks.

I can't get this to work

```
model.add(LSTM(N, input_shape=(T, N), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(N, input_shape=(T, N), return_sequences=False)) 
model.add(Dense(N))
```

However, I CAN get this to work

```
model.add(LSTM(N, input_shape=(T, N), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(N, input_shape=(T, N), return_sequences=True)) # True here 
model.add(Dense(N))
```

What's wrong with return_sequences=True if the output includes that last timestep, which is the f(t+1) that I'm looking for? I suppose nothing but this doesn't fix the fundamental problem which is that I don't fully understand how to build these networks. Like I said, I want to keep things as general as possible and deeply understand the networks before I start diving into experiments.

I will be running experiments with very different values for B, T and N to see which works the best.

I've tried to read the docs and whatnot but I'm quite stuck and getting frustrated so I thought I would turn to the community.

Comment: Is the first network(where return_sequences is set to False) yielding an error? Or is it simply not producing the intended result?

Comment: Error expected lstm_2 to have two dimensions but it received array of shape (1, T, N)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code helps
eg if number of nodes in each layer is 150

```
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(T,N)))
model.add(LSTM(150))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

And  remove input_shape=(T, N), in second lstm in your code.You have specified that it expects 2D array(T,N) but the first LSTM provides a 3d array consisting of (1,T,N)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I got another error, however which is

Comment: what error did u get,,return_sequences=True returns a 3D array ,,if u have multiple layers of lstm u should set it to True except for the last one....And also u have written that ur input shape is (T, N) i hope u have converted it to a 3D array before giving it to lstm  (total number of records(rows),T(timestep),N(number of dimenstion)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for specifying the `input_shape` argument in the second recurrent layer. This parameter is expressly required when the recurrent layer is the first layer in the network, but not otherwise.

If you wish to specify the input batch shape at each recurrent layer, remember to set the parameter `stateful = True` to render your LSTMs stateful(and only use this argument at the first layer of your network).

Comment: After removing the input_shape argument I got: Error when checking target: expected lstm_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 8, 11)

Comment: Is the first LSTM layer the first layer in your network?

Comment: Yes, the very first layer is the first LSTM you see in the question

Comment: Perhaps this article will help diagnose your problem: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

Comment: Nope, I've already perused that article. They never do return_sequences=False.

Comment: Which backend engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179775/discussion-between-pranav-vempati-and-derek-fulton).